# AWS.SQS: How can I get the atributtes from a messaje in a EB worker environment (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I created a sample app where I read messages from AWS SQS queue. Fifo if it matters, but I doubt.
I managed to get the body of the message and write it in DB, but I don't see where are the other information, like the attributes?
Being in a worker env connected to the queue, when a new message is created the app gets called via POST so I use `req.on('data', function (chunk){...}`.

'chunk' contains the body string (as Buffer actually).

How can I find the custom attribute? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I post it here in case anybody else need it.

The `req.headers` contains:

```
{ host: 'localhost',
  'x-real-ip': '127.0.0.1',
  'x-forwarded-for': '127.0.0.1',
  'content-length': '13',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'user-agent': 'aws-sqsd/2.3',
  'x-aws-sqsd-msgid': 'dbba278c-0463-47e4-a718-54c86dd004e0',
  'x-aws-sqsd-receive-count': '1',
  'x-aws-sqsd-first-received-at': '2017-08-17T18:18:45Z',
  'x-aws-sqsd-sent-at': '2017-08-17T18:18:45Z',
  'x-aws-sqsd-queue': 'queue1.fifo',
  'x-aws-sqsd-path': '',
  'x-aws-sqsd-sender-id': '...your-id....',
  'x-aws-sqsd-attr-<atribute name>': '<atribute value>' }
```